# python extract uncompressed data from 7z-file

Tags: python, 7zip, lzma

I have several csv-files, some of which are compressed but others are not, all in a 7z archive. I want to read the csv files and save the content in a database. However, whenever py7zlib attemts to read the data from a csv file that is actually not compressed, I get the error `data error during decompression`.

```
import os
import py7zlib

scr = r'Y:\PathtoArchive'
z7file = 'ArchiveName.7z'

with open(os.path.join(scr,z7file),'rb') as f:
    archive = py7zlib.Archive7z(f)

    names = archive.filenames

    for mem in names:

        obj = archive.getmember(mem)
        print obj.compressed  # prints None for uncompressed data
        try:
            data = obj.read()
        except Exception as er:
            print er          # prints data error during decompression
                              # whenever obj.compressed is None
```

The error happens in

```
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py7zlib.py", line 608, in read
data = getattr(self, decoder)(coder, data, level)
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py7zlib.py", line 671, in _read_lzma
return self._read_from_decompressor(coder, dec, input, level, checkremaining=True, with_cache=True)
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py7zlib.py", line 646, in _read_from_decompressor
tmp = decompressor.decompress(data)
ValueError: data error during decompression
```

So, how can I extract uncompressed data from a 7z-Archive?

Comment: Does the compressed file have a password?

Comment: no. none of the files have a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I couldn't really figure out what the problem seemed to be, I found a workaround that solved the ultimate goal to obtain the data from csv-files from a 7z-archive.
7-zip comes with a command line tool. Communicating with that tool via the subprocess module, I could automatically extract the files that I wihsed to extract without any problems

```
import subprocess
import py7zlib 

archiveman = r'c:\Program Files\7-zip\7z' # 7z.exe comes with 7-zip
archivepath = r'C:\Path\to\archive.7z'

with open(archivepath,'rb') as f:
    archive = py7zlib.Archive7z(f)
    names = archive.filenames
    for name in names:
        _ = subprocess.check_output([archiveman, 'e', archivepath, '-o{}'.format(r'C:\Destination\of\copy'), name])
```

The different commands that can be used with 7z can be found [here](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/).

Answer (score 1):

You can try another library, [py7zr](https://github.com/miurahr/py7zr/), which also supports 7zip archive compression, decompression, encryption and decryption.
https://pypi.org/project/py7zr